# 'selectionStart' property exists (?) but cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, selection-api

In my simple bookmarklet, I call all `input` elements of the document, and then try to try to access `selectionStart` of each element:

```
javascript: (function () {
 var inps=document.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) {
   var el = inps[i];
         if ('selectionStart' in el) {
           console.log("o: " + (typeof el));
           console.log("x: " + (typeof el.nonexistent));
           console.log("s: " + (typeof el.selectionStart));
         }
 } 


})();
```

this code gives the following lines in the console:
 "o: object" - as expected,
 "x: undefined" - as expected,
but for `el.selectionStart` no output is given and "NS_ERROR_FAILURE" is shown in the console. Can anybody explain why does this happen? (additional general question - where can I find the meaning or any details about such errors thrown by Firefox?)

Comment: In Chrome, the error says: `Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access `selectionStart` of a type `hidden` element, or even type `button`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pbCnQ/

[image]

Comment: you're right, and it will also be the case for checkbox etc.
 thanks a lot!